# Need add-on for Firefox to change proxy easily

Tags: firefox, proxy

I got a list of proxies. Some from Egypt, some from Italy, etc.

Say I want to use a certain proxy. One way to do so is to go to Tools → Options bla bla.

Is there an add-on that make this faster?

I want to see how a site looks in some countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you take a look at **FoxyProxy**, which is available in two flavors: a [standard version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/) and another [basic version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-basic/):

[image: FoxyProxy] [image: FoxyProxy]
<sup>*FoxyProxy* (source: [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

You setup your proxies once by picking them from a list and assigning them a color. Then you can switch easily via a dropdown – or even have *FoxyProxy* switch them automatically based on hostnames or other "patterns".

I've used it for quite a while some time ago, and really liked it. Didn't make any trouble, but simply did its job smoothly. Really recommendable.